# Is it possible in gitlab to push an update commit without documenting it?

Tags: git, gitlab, commit

I have sent a request to merge a `new_change` branch into the `master` branch. Now I want to make minor updates in the `new_change` branch and push them to the remote.

However, if I push my changes, the fact that I made a push will be recorded either as one more commit or an extra message appended to the current commit. In the changes tab, a new "version" will appear (next to the `latest version` and `version 1`, I will see a `version 2`).

Is there a way to push a commit, such that only the files would be changed without adding any documentation?

If I have `latest version` and `version 1`, can I push a commit in a way that would not add `verion 2` to the list but only update the `latest version`?

Comment: Since you mentioned "merge request", can we assume that the remote branch is on GitLab?

Comment: @Enrico Campidoglio yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Looking at the [push options supported by GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-merge-requests), there isn't one to skip creating a new update to a merge request.

Of course, this might change in the future.